# Unit tests for a single python file

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have a python script with main, and a whole lot of helper methods. How do I write unit tests for these helper methods which all reside in the same file. A lot of the examples I see online involve creating libraries of helpers and then importing and testing that. In my case it is all one file.

Sample structure:

```
/user/
  |-- pythonscript.py
```

and I want to write tests for `pythonscript.py`.

Sample `pythonscript.py`:

```
def getSum(i ,j):
    return i+j

def main():
    summer = getSum(1,1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For example, I want to write tests for methods like `getSum` in another file. (I recall there was a tester which would screen `.py` files and identify functions needing tests based on appending `test_` or `_test`, but I cannot seem to find it anymore.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/), which can [automatically discover tests](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/goodpractices.html#test-discovery) that follow certain naming and path conventions. One of these is considering every function prefixed with `test` to be a test.

For your scenario, I'd recommend creating a file called `test_pythonscript.py` also at the root of your directory. Inside that file, you could import functions from `pythonscript.py`, then test them:

```py
# test_pythonscript.py
from pythonscript import getSum

test_getSum():
    assert getSum(1, 2) == 3
```

Once you've installed `pytest` as a dependency, you'd run `pytest` at the root of your project and it should be able to discover the above test.

Comment: interesting, I get `E   ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: [This worked though](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28151907/2883071): changing `from .pythonscript` to `from pythonscript`. Thank you

Comment: Oops, I'll fix my answer 